# Ionic + Angular App Only Renders Dynamic HTML with encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am having a tough time understanding what the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` within the `@Component`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Within my `home.page.scss`, if I set styles for:

```
.responsive {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;

    iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

And then I bring in HTML from a API with dynamic HTML like:

```
 <div class="responsive"><iframe src="https://foo/bar"></iframe></div>
```

The code will render it just fine, but if I remove `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` from the `@Component`, the HTML and CSS is not rendered.

This is the code for the `home.page.html` template:

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

And this is the code for the `home.page.ts`:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  content: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //res.content comes from a service
    this.content = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res.content);
  }
}
```

Can someone help explain what is going on, and why the dynamic HTML will not be rendered without the encapsulation?

Comment: Edit for some additional information/clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) strategies:

1. Emulated (Default): no shadow DOM, styles encapsulated per component (parent, child components will have their styles "isolated") as if you added `<style>...</style>` to each component inside your component tree and made sure they do not spill over
2. Native: with Shadow DOM, styles encapsulation to the shadow DOM created (at "parent" level, styles of parent will affect children) as if you added `<style>...</style>` to the Shadow DOM's root
3. None: no Shadow DOM, no styles encapsulation (styles apply across the board) as if you added your styles to the `<head><style>...</style></head>`

Now what happens in your case:

When you use ViewEncapsulation.None - the styles within home.page.scss become available across the DOM and once you are adding (btw innerHTML is not the best way to do it...) to the HomePage's DOM tree, those styles apply and you see iFrame etc rendered

When you switch to ViewEncapsulation.Emulated (Default) - the styles of home.page.scss do not affect the children elements you are adding (styles are "encapsulated") and no style is applied and you see no rendering

If you try ViewEncapsulation.Native - the styles will be available (if Shadow DOM is supported) at Shadow DOM root level and thus the styles should be still available to

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's much appreciated. I have a couple follow up questions. One) Should the ViewEncapsulation even be needed when injecting html from an API service? Two) What is the better way for adding the injected HTML outside of innerHTML?

Comment: for a) if you inject HTML (as string) you just need to keep in mind that the style information of the host information won't magically apply to such newly added DOM in case of default encapsulation and you can always "inline" style data.

Comment: for b) its just preferable to avoid such direct DOM manipulation due to security, performance (innerHTML change will cause layout/reflow) etc. So it depends on your use case, ideally I would template it and use API received data only as instruction which template to show etc. But if you have truly dynamic needs, you may use Dynamic Component Factory etc. Worst case - consider inserts using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML